# A strange rule for determine convexity of optimization constraint?

Tags: soft-question, convex-optimization

I am an electrical engineer who is currently working with some optimization problem. One of my senior has a strange rule of thumb to determine the convexity of constraint for minimization problem.

His rules for this constraint are listed as follows:

$f\left( x \right) \le g\left( x \right)$

1/ If $f\left( x \right)$ is a convex function and $g\left( x \right)$ is a linear function then the constraint $f\left( x \right) \le g\left( x \right)$ can be written as a convex constraint.

2/ If $f\left( x \right)$ is a convex function and $g\left( x \right)$ is a concave function then the constraint $f\left( x \right) \le g\left( x \right)$ can be written as a convex constraint.

The problem is that most people in my group just follow this without asking any question. Therefore, I was wondering if this is true or not since there is no proof.

Would you kindly help me with this ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Yes, it's true because if $g$ is concave then $-g$ is convex, and a convex ineq. constraint is written as $f(x)\leq 0$ with $f$ convex. An affine function is both convex and concave.

Comment: I am sorry but does both rule 1 and rule 2 are true

Comment: Yes, please check [this](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) book, and specifically sections 3.1 and 4.2.